# Can I do the traditional marriage ceremony few years after the nikah?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

There is someone I fall in love with. And so I want to marry her. Cause before marriage touching her will be a Zina. So I want to marry her. But she wants to have a traditional ceremony. Or at least a big feast. Traditional feast. And I am from Bangladesh. So a traditional marriage ceremony is very expressive. Also there are a lot of other reasons. So right now it's not possible for me. But again I don't want to commit Zina. so is it possible to do the ceremony few years after the nikah? When I will have no other problem to make a traditional ceremony or feast. Till then she can stay in her place and I can stay at my place but we will have a halal relationship by signing the marriage contract. Is it possible to do the ceremony few years after the actual nikah?

Answer (score 1):

The traditional marriage ceremony is just that, tradition. Islam is not concerned with it. Islam only cares about the Nikah, which is the actual marriage.

So, unless, the lady or her parents make a condition on the Nikah that you have to do the ceremony immediately after the Nikah, there is no problem. If both the lady and her parents agree to allow what you want to do, it is a completely legitimate marriage.